# Map not displayed when plotting points

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm trying to plot the points onto a map with geopandas but when I do plot the points the map disappears.

```
fp = "./nyu_2451_34490/nyu_2451_34490.shp"

map_df = gpd.read_file(fp)

map_df = map_df.to_crs(epsg=4326)

geometry = [Point(x) for x in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}, geometry=geometry)
```

Without the points the map does show up

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
base = map_df.plot(ax=ax, color='gray')
# gdf.plot(ax=ax, markersize=5)
```

[image]

But when I do

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
base = map_df.plot(ax=ax, color='gray')
gdf.plot(ax=ax, markersize=5)
```

[image]

Comment: can you show the definition of gdf?

Comment: @BrunoCarballo updated

Comment: Look at the scale; I guess, that the map is still there, but it is *very* small

Answer (score 3):

If it has longitude and latitude in shape file, how about using scatter to plot the points?

```
plt.scatter("longitude", "latitude", data=df)
```

In addition, it looks like the points have different scale or the plot is showing too wide area. Setting the limit of x and y axis may help.

```
#set_xlim(left, right)
ax.set_xlim(-74.3, -73.6)
#set_ylim(bottom, top)
ax.set_ylim(40.4, 50.0)
```

Hope this helps.